# Why does this particular Vim RegEx string work?

Tags: regex, vim

I had spent a while trying to narrow down a way of retrieving only web links from a few thousand lines that ended with either `jpg` or `png`.

If I use

```
%s/\(http.*\(jpg\|png\)\)\=\(.*\|\_s\)/\1/g|%s/\n\=
```

I can grab links just fine. The some thousands of lines are removed and replaced by only matching links. But if I remove the first `\=`, like here

```
%s/\(http.*\(jpg\|png\)\)\(.*\|\_s\)/\1/g|%s/\n\=
```

nothing in the file is changed or removed, and all the text is highlighted as a match.

If I remove it from the end of the pattern string, it concatenates every match onto a single line. I understand the basic reason for why this happens (being used by itself). That said, I am lost as to why it does not happen *the same way* when used in this specific case. (Meaning, the links do not get piled onto one line.)

My questions are:

- **Why do the links remain unchanged in the first example rather than replace the entire file or be removed entirely?**
- **Why does specifying `\n` as an optional element not remove the nulls when the meaning of `\=` is "*match 0 OR 1*"?**

Comment: Try changing `.*` to `.*?`

Comment: @Bohemian This doesn't work in vim. It works with Perl compatible regexes only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the end of your regexp, with

```
%s/\n\=
```

You're substituting in every line 0 or 1 \n with //, hence and since you're *not* using the g flag, in any line that begins with anything but a \n, there'll be a match of the 0 part and nothing will be substituted with nothing: i.e. the line remains the same. (Led zeppelin quote)

It's equivalent to:

```
:%s/^\n
```

If you remove the \=, the first \n *actually* found in every line will be removed, that's why empty lines and the newlines at the end of your *non* empty lines get removed.

Now, here:

```
%s/\(http.*\(jpg\|png\)\)\=\(.*\|\_s\)/\1/g
```

The \= makes so that *any* string with 0 or 1 `\(http.*\(jpg\|png\)\)` patterns followed by *anything* (since you have `\(.*\|\_s\)`), will be replaced by the first saved pattern.

Basically, you're matching your *whole* file and preventing only this pattern: `\(http.*\(jpg\|png\)\)` from being removed.

When you remove \=, the 0 part of the match drops, and only in the lines that actually have the `\(http.*\(jpg\|png\)\)` pattern there will be a substitution of the matched pattern with *itself* from http up to jpg/png with anything after that being removed.

On a side note, if you save a pattern but don't use it in the substitution string, you're losing that pattern anyway.

If you actually only want to *keep* the http..jpg/png lines and remove the others, you can use the g! or v command:

```
:v/http.*jpg\|png/d
```

deletes all the lines that *don't* have the matched pattern.